# Запрос к таблице где значение НЕ равно YYY

Tags: mysql, sql

Быстренький вопрос.

Нужен запрос который проверяет условие при котором значение в строке НЕ равно, например нулю.

`select * from articles where age != 18;`

(!=) - Такое существует?

Comment: такое точно существует `<>`

Comment: @splash58  select * from articles where age > 0; То есть так можно?

Comment: если сравнивать с нулем, можно просто  where age

Comment: конечно возможно, но конкретный синтаксис зависит от субд, какая у вас?

Comment: @Anatol mysql. Проблема решена. splash58 помог)

Comment: @splash58, далеко не все SQL диалекты такое поддерживают

Comment: @MaxU я человек дикий, для меня вопрос про субд, если не уточнений, - про mysql. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Технически `<>` является частью `SQL-92 ANSI Standard`, а `!=` - нет.

Большинство известных мне SQL диалектов поддерживают оба варианта.

Иногда случаются курьезные случаи - [в Oracle 10.2 было замечено, что CBO (Cost Based Optimizer) строил разные планы выполнения в зависимости от использования `<>` или `!=`](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_not_equal_operator.htm):

PS также можно переписать ваш запрос следующим образом:

```
select * from articles where NOT age = 18;
```

Answer (score 2):

Не встречал еще ни 1 БД, в которой бы знак `<>` не работал.

```
select * from articles where age <> 18;
```